# Activity's title is getting cropped/ellipseze

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity

I got this issue,  FragmentActivities title getting cropped everytime user come back to this screen from next.

[image]

Any pointer?

Using `fragmentActivity.setTitle`?

Comment: Can you post code for Activity and its related fragment.Specailly one that involves title and onResume()

Comment: Show us your Toolbar XML layout and anything else you inflate into it programmatically. If you use custom Toolbar style post that as well. Post the menu XML too. ||| Finally go to Developer Settings on your phone, enable Show layout bounds and post a screenshot.